# Написал чат с использованием ajax и php. И столкнулся с тем что скрипт не может посчитать кол-во сообщений

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Вот код jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit").on("click", getRequest);
$(document).on("keydown",function (event) {
/*при нажатии Enter отправляется сообщение*/
if(event.keyCode == 13){
getRequest();
}
})
});
/*Функция которая отправляет данные асинхронно*/
function getRequest() {
var date = new Date();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
if(minutes < 10){
minutes = "0"+minutes;
}

var  json = {     /*Данные для передачи    */
id:getId()+1,
message: $("#message").val(),
time:date.getHours()+":"+minutes
}
/*Строка для вывода на страницу в настоящее время*/
var string = "<div class = 'deserve'><div id = 'name'><p>Антон Томаштик</p></div><div id = 'mess'>"+json.message+"</div><div id = 'time'> "+json.time+"</div><span class='close'></span></div><div class='id' type='hidden'>:"+json.id+"</div>";
 if(json.message != ""){
$.ajax({       /* */
url:"mind.php",
type:"POST",
data: {json:JSON.stringify(json)},
success:function (data) {
/*Добавляю строки на дисплей не дожидаясь ответа с сервера*/
$("#display").append(string); 
$("#message").val("");
}


});
  }else{
    $(".result").html("Сообщение пустует");
  }
  }


function getId(){ /*Основная проблема здесь*/
    var id;

 id = document.getElementsByClassName("deserve").lenght;
/* id возвращает undefined хотя на экране сообщений много, он их не считает*/ 
console.log("дисплей не пустой и в нём "+id+" элементов");

  return id;
}
```

Для чего я вообще написал последний блок с переменной id? Для того чтобы у каждого сообщения был свой id, по которому я бы мог удалять эти же сообщения. Я разными способами пытался их посчитать. Но не получалось и этим методом (.getElementsByClassName()).
Далее запрос идет в файл mind.php и там же записывается в файл где хранятся сообщения:

```
<?php
################################################################### 
# Обработка и запись запроса
################################################################### 
$arr = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
$fileW = fopen("files/message.txt", "a+") or die();
fwrite($fileW,  "<div class = 'deserve'><div id = 'name'><p>Антон Томаштик</p></div><div id = 'mess'>".wordwrap(trim($arr["message"]),25)."</div><div id = 'time'> ".$arr["time"]."</div><span class='close'></span></div><div class='kek' type='hidden'>:".$arr['id']."</div>");

fclose($fileW);
###################################################################
```

На index.php находится #display где все эти сообщение отображаются:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Чат</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/display-style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">




<div id = "display"> 
<?php 
###################################################
#Чтение и запись на дисплей
###################################################

$fileR = fopen("files/message.txt","r");
while(!feof($fileR)){
echo fgets($fileR);

#Блок кода печатает все сообщения на #display

            }
fclose($fileR);
###################################################

?>

</div><br>
<!-- Поля для ввода и кнопка отправки -->
<textarea id="message" cols="50"  rows = "3" name="message"></textarea>  
<input style= "margin-left: 20px;" id="submit" type="button" value="Отправить" name="submit">
</div>
<div style="color:white; margin-left: 20px;" class="result"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Я понимаю что с базой данных было бы проще, но хотелось бы понять в чем суть.
И вот что получается в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]